# Tabular table shows odd space between two columns

Tags: tables, spacing, vertical

I have edited the below table with `\usepackage{booktabs}`.

However, between the first and second regression, there is an odd vertical space. How do I remove the space between these two columns and get them all aligned with the same vertical space in between?
[image: table]

```
\begin{table}[thb]
    \centering
    \label{tab:first_wave_week}
    \small
    \scriptsize
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{1pt}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
    \caption{First Covid-19 wave - Dependent Variable: Transactions_{it}} \\ 
    \vskip 3pt
    \begin{tabular}{l dddd}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Regressors}       
    & \mc{\textbf{(1)}} 
    & \mc{\textbf{(2)}} 
    & \mc{\textbf{(3)}}
    & \mc{\textbf{(4)}}
    \\
    \midrule
    Covid-19_{it}       
    & -0.1094^{***}
    & -0.0869^{***}
    & -0.1014^{***}
    & -0.0891^{***}
    \\
    & (0.0406)
    & (0.0312)
    & (0.0423)
    & (0.0332)
    \\
    Trans_{it{-1}}   
    &    
    & 0.5993^{***}
    &
    & 0.6026^{***}
    \\
    &    
    & (0.0105)
    &
    & (0.0107)
    \\
    Trans_{it{-2}}   
    &    
    & 0.0995^{***}
    &
    & 0.0993^{***}
    \\
    &    
    & (0.0054)
    &
    & (0.0055)
    \\
    Unemp_{it}   
    &    
    &
    & -0.2598^{***}
    & -0.0785
    \\
    &    
    &
    & (0.0669)
    & (0.0527)
    \\
    \midrule
    $N$        
    & \mc{332} 
    & \mc{332}
    & \mc{332}
    & \mc{319}
    \\
    $T$        
    & \mc{30} 
    & \mc{30} 
    & \mc{30} 
    & \mc{30}  
    \\
    $FE$        
    & \mc{Both} 
    & \mc{Both} 
    & \mc{Both} 
    & \mc{Both} 
    \\
    $R^{2}$    
    & 0.0010   
    & 0.3800
    & 0.0031
    & 0.3840
    \\
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{(Standard errors clustered by municipality in parentheses)}\\
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{$^{***}\ p<0.01$; $^{**}\ p<0.05$; $^{*}\ p<0.1$}\\
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    \\
```

Comment: look at your note at the bottom, you said it only spanned two columns so those columns had to be enlarged chaneg`\multicolumn{2}` to `\multicolumn{5}` or take the notes out of the `tabular`

Comment: You are right! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `threeparttable` and `tablenotes` for table notes, `S` column tape defined in the `siunitx` package and `\thead` command defined in the `makecell`  for column headers:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
    \renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}    % considered is v3

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
\sisetup{
    table-align-text-before= false, % <---
    input-open-uncertainty =,
    input-close-uncertainty=,
    table-format={(}-1.4{$^{***}$},
         }
\begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{First Covid-19 wave - Dependent Variable: Transactions\textsubscript{it}} 
\begin{tabular}{l *{4}{S} }
    \toprule
\thead{Regressors}
    & {\thead{(1)}}
        & {\thead{(2)}}
            & {\thead{(3)}}
                & {\thead{(4)}} \\
    \midrule
Covid-19\textsubscript{it}
    & -0.1094\tnote{***}
        & -0.0869\tnote{***}
            & -0.1014\tnote{***}
                & -0.0891\tnote{***}    \\
    & (0.0406)
        & (0.0312)
            & (0.0423)
                & (0.0332)              \\
    \addlinespace
Trans\textsubscript{it - 1}
    &   & 0.5993\tnote{***}
            &   & 0.6026\tnote{***}     \\
    &   & (0.0105)
            &   & (0.0107)              \\
    \addlinespace
Trans\textsubscript{it - 2}
    &   & 0.0995\tnote{***}
            &   & 0.0993\tnote{***}     \\
    &   & (0.0054)
            &   & (0.0055)              \\
    \addlinespace
Unemp\textsubscript{it}
    &   &   & -0.2598\tnote{***}
                & -0.0785               \\
    &   &   & (0.0669)
                & (0.0527)              \\
    \midrule
$N$ & {332}
        & {332}
            & {332}
                & {319}                 \\
$T$ & {30}
        & {30}
            & {30}
                & {30}                  \\
$FE$
    & {Both}
        & {Both}
            & {Both}
                & {Both}                \\
$R^{2}$
    & 0.0010
        & 0.3800
            & 0.0031
                & 0.3840                \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}[flushleft, para]\footnotesize
\note{Standard errors clustered by municipality are in parentheses:}\\
    \item[***]  $p<0.01$,
    \item[**]   $p<0.05$,
    \item[*]    $p<0.1$
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]